# how to create edit text in oncontextitemselected option like pop up

Tags: android, menu

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
               //     ArrayList<String> names = s;


                    switch(item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.renameplaylist:

                        //here i click my player option rename playlist contextmenu means i want open one edittext after i edit and save it.
```

Comment: where i give that are given line...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a customDialog with an EditText with two buttons, if ok is clicked save the editText info on your player list.

You can follow the API for [CustomDialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog)

Or you can make a new activity for that purpose and set it as a dialog style...

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Or with a normal activity and startActivityForResult...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create [Custom Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) for that. Good luck!